# Nested list Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested

How do I get a nested list like this :

[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, [7,8], 9]], 0]

to show like this => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

using recursion?

Can anyone help?

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212). Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flat()`. `flat` only removes one level of nested array by default. However, you can specify how much nested levels you want to remove in parameter. In your case, `3` does the trick.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, [7,8], 9]], 0]

function flatten(arr){
  return arr.flat(3)
}

console.log(flatten(a))
```